# console log is being clear

Tags: javascript, console

I guess this has to do with a library that was installed.
but I don't know which one is it or when this started.
I get this is my console log every second:
"Console was cleared" in the entire site.
if I select "Preserve log" I get:
"console.clear() was prevented due to 'Preserve log'"

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: ... and what is the used library?

Comment: My question is how can I figure out what is causing it?
And I don't know what library is it, I don't know it is a library, I'm just assuming that

Comment: How could we figure it out based on the information you've provided? If you know it is not written in your own code, drop the libraries one by one until the log flood stops. Then if you get stuck when removing the logging code, ask a question. Also, the console shows a link to the line where `console.clear()` appeared, you can follow the link ...

Comment: it is not coming directly from my code.
this is the link I'm getting:
https://eluxer.net/code?id=105&subid=51824_7220_
which does not give me too much info.
before posting the question, I tried to remove any lines with anything to do with console clear but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

I figure out it was a chrome extension, once I removed them all it solve the problem. So it was not my code at the end of all

Comment: This actually just happened to me with firefox.. I haven't done any web dev work since firebug was removed from the dev tools, so this was infuriating, and your suggestion helped me, and even better, worked. Thanks for posting the solution after being downvoted. Now to work out which extension it was

Answer (score 1):

For me, this issue was caused by the "SaveFrom.net helper" browser extension. Removing or disabling that extension resolved the problem.